# sql server 2005 restore is stuck in restoring

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, database-backups, database-restore

I am setting up a second server for database mirroring running [SQL server] 2005. I performed a full database backup from the production server. I am restoring that database to the secondary (mirroring) server. The restore begins but just stays stuck in restoring. I have done some research and found that the database will get stuck in restoring if you have chosen `NORECOVERY` as the recovery state, which I have chosen. However I chose `NORECOVERY` because I read that is the state you want when restoring.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have 9 databases I need to restore and then configure the mirroring.

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct state to be in -- it's not stuck.

Don't put the DB into RECOVERY mode.  You can and should begin mirroring onto the secondary when the database is still in this mode.

Once mirroring is enabled, you'll see that your database will change from "Restoring..." to "Synchronizing...", which means mirroring is working properly.